# Lotus Notes get just selected mails via OLE

Tags: email, lotus-notes, lotus-domino, ole, lotus

I am trying to get selected mails from Lotus Notes via OLE. So far I was doing it like this:

```
 UIView := FLNotes.CURRENTVIEW;
 UIDocuments := UIView.DOCUMENTS;

   for counter := 1 to UIDocuments.Count do begin
     if counter = 1 Then
       aDocument := UIDocuments.GETFIRSTDOCUMENT
     else
       aDocument := UIDocuments.GETNEXTDOCUMENT(aDocument);

     ProcessDokument (aDocument)
```

When I am inside this mail view it works as expected, I get just the mails I put the checkmark next to (so I get 2 mails)
  [image]
Now I want to search for a particular mail that has "sem" somewhere, and I switch to the search tab:

[image]

Now I have the problem that my code returns all the visible documents, and not just the one I have selected. Here I didnt select any of them, but still my for loop runs 7 times for every document.

My question, why are all the documents being processed even I didnt select any of them, especially, why is the behaviour different than when I am inside the mailbox. And is there a way to identify just the ones I have selected ?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that after the full text search, you're not really in a view. You're in  full text search result list that looks like a view but it's really an overlay on top of the view. If you could see the actual view, the documents that are in the result list would be selected!

There is no method in the [NotesUIWorkspace class](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSVRGU_8.5.3/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_NOTESUIWORKSPACE_CLASS.html) for getting the current full text search result list that you are seeing (and no NotesUIFTSearchResults class for representing it, either) so I don't believe there's any way to get access to the documents that you've manually selected within the result list.

What you might be able to do is get data for all of the docs in the result list, build a dialog box and show that to the user, let the user select the docs in the dialog box instead of in the result list itself, and then have your code act on the ones that the user has selected - but without seeing your code and knowing what it's trying to do in your ProcessDokument() routine, I don't know if that's reasonable or not.